# Deploying image to K8 - error: standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have containerized a simple python application to run on a GCP Kubernetes cluster. I built the image from an Apple M1 Max Macbook, using the `--platform=linux/amd64` argument. I keep getting a pod status of `Does not have minimum availability` with the following in the logs `error: standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error` when I deploy the image via a `yml` file.

This is strange because I have successfully used a custom image, built with the `--platform=linux/amd64` argument on the same Macbook, when delpying a neo4j database to the same kubernetes cluster.

Below is how I'm currently attempting to deploy the python application. I've gone down several rabbit holes to try and fix the error, including using alpine python images, which complicates the usage of my `pandas` and `numpy` packages. And I've tried building a multiarch image, although I'm not sure if I targeted the correct platforms as can't find the GCP Kubernetes platform type.

**How do I successfully deploy an image of a python application, built on my M1 mac, to a GCP K8 cluster?**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    python3 python3-dev gcc \
    gfortran musl-dev



WORKDIR /usr/app/src

COPY . /usr/app/src
COPY requirements.txt /usr/app/src/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools



RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt


ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./execute.py"]
```

Docker commands:

`docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t example/image:latest .`

`docker push example/image:latest`

example.yml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: p2e-daily-updates-kub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: p2e-daily-updates-kub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: p2e-daily-updates-kub
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: p2e-daily-updates-kub
          image: "example/image:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: p2e-bots-secrets
                  key: TOKEN
            - name: slack_channel
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: p2e-bots-secrets
                  key: slack_channel
            - name: slack_token
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: p2e-bots-secrets
                  key: slack_token
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

kubectl command:
`kubectl apply -f example.yml`

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it
 for the greater visibility of community

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question:

How do I successfully deploy an image of a python application, built on my M1 mac, to a GCP K8 cluster?

Well, actually you need to connect your GCP K8 cluster to a private registry ( let's say a Google artifacts registry)

1. Create GC artifacts registry

For example:

```bash
gcloud artifacts repositories create $REGISTRY_NAME --repository-format=docker \
    --location=us-central1 --description="testing-docker-repository"
#verify repository
gcloud artifacts repositories list
```

Please see https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-push-docker-image

2. Push local Image to GC artifacts registry

```bash
#connect Docker to Private artifacts registry
gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.test
```

```bash
# tag image
gcloud builds submit --tag us-central1-docker.pkg.test/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY_NAME}/example/image:latest .
# push
docker push us-central1-docker.pkg.test/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY_NAME}/example/image:latest
```

3. Create Service Account to pull images from GC Container Registry to GCP K8s CLuster

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
    --iam-account=sa-link-artifacts@otcs${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Create docker-registry that holds the service account
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE create secret docker-registry uat-artifact-registry \
    --docker-server=https://us-central1-docker.**** \
    --docker-email=sa-link-artifacts@otcs${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --docker-username=_json_key \
    --docker-password="$(cat key.json)"
```

For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

This way, you can pull images from your Google Artifacts Registry into your GKE cluster

Comment: Well if you don't need them private, you just need to specify the full image address with docker.hub.io when pulling from docker hub